# How would I implement a dropdownitem in KIVYMD,

Tags: python, kivy, dropdown, kivy-language

I currently have a small scale GUI build as I am just messing around with code, but something I can't seem to figure out after long research is how to implement a drop drown list/item into my code as its on a set screen.

That might be explained badly but this is currently my main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class ExampleApp(MDApp):


    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
        return kv


ExampleApp().run()
```

And this is my kv file

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    Screen:
        name: "land"
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: "center"
            anchor_y: "top"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 0.2,0.2

                MDLabel:
                    text: "What is your weight?"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"

                    MDTextField:
                        input_filter: "float"
                        on_text_validate:

                    MDDropDownItem:
                        text: "a"

                    MDIconButton:
                        icon: "android"



    Screen:
        name: "second"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Second"
```

Now the part that I don't understand is how from the land screen can I make that MDDropdownItem functional but also have it be a child of that screen only

Another question is, Say I can make the list/dropdown menu functional how would I add custom text to the list that opens without using a for loop that would be in range

This drop down would be in theory as such

- The clickable list

  - Option 1
  - Option 2 # The only difference being that its not the same text as its a custom text list

-The clickable list

- Blah
- Mawh 2
- Random

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but have you looked into the [Kivy Spinner?](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.spinner.html). I have never tried KivyMD, but a Spinner widget may be what you want

Answer (score 0):

The way to place custom text and icons in MDdropdownMenu is to place several dictionaries in a list.

Exemple:

```
menu_items = [
{"icon": "git", "text": "Blah"}
{"icon": "android", "text": "Mawh 2"}
{"icon": "stack-overflow", "text": "Random"}
]
```

As for the first question, I couldn't quite understand what you mean, could you be more explicit?